# How to create new file after building jlink app?

Tags: java

I am a new in modular java and I cannot understand how to create a new file after building jlink app. For example, I have an application with next project structure:

```
src
 main
   java
     com
       example
         App.java
         User.java
   resources
     com
       example
         files
```

And I want to create serialisation and deserialisation. I've created simple user class:

```
public class User implements Externalizable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4913943031221551392L;

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(this.name);
        out.writeObject(this.surname);
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.name = (String) in.readObject();
        this.surname = (String) in.readObject();
    }
}
```

In App.java I have method for simple deserialisation:

```
private static User restoreModel() {
    User user = null;
    InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream("files/test.bin");
    if (is != null) {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is)) {
            user = (User) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ignore) {}
    }
    return user;
}
```

It will work okay when I had already saved user before in my app but If it’s the first start of the app and the user doesn’t have a created file "test.bin" in resources->com->example->files. And my question is how to create this file "test.bin" when application was built by jlink?